# add_feed and flush_rewrite_rules

Tags: rewrite-rules, init, feed

There seems to be quite a controversial opinion on the WordPress `flush_rewrite_rules()` function.

According to the Codex, it is highly discouraged to use this function on the `init` action hook.

**However:**

In a plugin I am working on, I am using `add_feed()` to, well, add a feed. The Codex says that this should be run on `init` and requires a one-time use of `flush_rewrite_rules()`.

See my dilemma ? I need `add_feed()` on `init`, which requires `flush_rewrite_rules()`.

Hence, `flush_rewrite_rules()` on `init`, which is breaking all custom post type rewrite rules and permalinks, resulting in 404 pages.

**So my question is:** how should this be done ?

This is what I currently have on `init`, that is related to the issue:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_foobar' );
function my_foobar() {
    // getting some settings
    add_feed( $url, $callback );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check the existing rewrite rules before you run a flush. If your feed name is `test`, they are stored under the keys `'feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom|test)/?$'` and `'(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom|test)/?$'`.

So this should do the trick:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{    
    $name       = 'test';
    $registered = FALSE;

    add_feed( $name, 'test_feed' );

    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );
    $feeds = array_keys( $rules, 'index.php?&feed=$matches[1]' );

    foreach ( $feeds as $feed )
    {
        if ( FALSE !== strpos( $feed, $name ) )
            $registered = TRUE;
    }

    // Feed not yet registered, so lets flush the rules once.
    if ( ! $registered )
        flush_rewrite_rules( FALSE );
});
```

Comment: Accepted! Works brilliantly. I guess that `$wp_rewrite` global variable slipped past me. Thanks

Comment: @Mekku That global variable isn’t even needed. I have removed it from my answer.

Comment: Yes I noticed after I commented. One quick question. Is the second parameter of the `array_keys` function treated as a regex pattern ?

Comment: No, just a search string.

Comment: So what is the reasoning behind using `$matches[1]` in the search string ? The string you used uses single quotes, so the string isn't even interpolated. Thanks

Comment: That’s the value you have to search for in the existing rules.

Comment: Ah ok. So in the end, `$feeds` will contain each matching key's second part. Thanks a bunch :)